# Javascript from codepen is not working in our website?

Tags: javascript

I added this JS using a WordPress plugin called simple CSS and Js. CSS, HTML are working. But JS is not working.

```
(function($) {

    // Handle click on toggle search button
    $('#toggle-search').click(function() {
        $('#search-form, #toggle-search').toggleClass('open');
        return false;
    });

    // Handle click on search submit button
    $('#search-form input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        $('#search-form, #toggle-search').toggleClass('open');
        return true;
    });

    // Clicking outside the search form closes it
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);

        if (!target.is('#toggle-search') && !target.closest('#search-form').size()) {
            $('#search-form, #toggle-search').removeClass('open');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/Linuance/pen/mAFeg?editors=0010

Comment: Did you add jQuery?

Comment: No errors in console?

Comment: I got no error in Codepen.io. But when I added this JS into my WordPress website. It's not responding.

Comment: Do you get an error in the console on **your** webpage? What does `It's not responding` mean, is the code executed, but do the `$('#toggle-search')`selectors find no elements?

Comment: Basically, it should toggle the search icon. But it's not toggling. http://www.epasand.com/ check out this website in mobile view. And you can find the error with search icon in top nav bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you JavaScript/jQuery is working just fine. When clicking the search icon the class 'open' is appended to the button and form. I think the issue lies within your CSS styling. Try this:

```
#search-form.open {
  max-height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Didn't pay attention to the styling, but this should show the search form.

Comment: Thanks... It is now solved. But see when I search something there, it doesn't go to the right URL. Means search is not working. Can you help me with this?

Comment: When I search for 'test' the search works just fine, the URL is showing http://www.epasand.com/?s=test&post_type=product. If it doesn't show the results corresponding to the search term then it can be two things, de data isn't send correctly with $_POST or in the back-end the search term isn't handled in the right way. However I guess this is something for another topic/qeustion.